# R - trying to save ARIMA model data to a text file

Tags: r

Hi and thanks in advance,

So I've got code that I've managed to produce my first functioning arima model graphs.

Now what I'm aiming to do is save that arima models forecasted data to a txt file, but i haven't been having any luck.

Here is my code:

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

#TEST DATA AND TEST CODE#
Quantity <- c(5,3,8,4,0,5,2,7,4,2,6,8,4,7,8,9,4,6)
Time <- c("2010-01-01", "2010-07-02", "2010-08-03", "2011-02-04", "2011-11-05", "2011-12-06", "2012-06-07", "2012-08-30", "2013-04-16", "2013-03-18", "2014-02-22", "2014-01-27", "2015-12-15", "2015-09-28", "2016-05-04", "2017-11-07", "2017-09-22", "2017-04-04")
QuantityFrame <- data.frame(Time,Quantity)
write.table(QuantityFrame,file="C:/....path..../QuantityFrame.txt",quote=F)

#THE FUNCTION#
Frame <- read.table("C:/....path..../QuantityFrame.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
Frame$Time <- as.Date(Frame$Time, format= "%Y-%m-%d")
Frame <- ts(Frame$Quantity, start = 1, end=NROW(Frame), frequency=1)

TheForecast <- arima(Frame, order = c(10,1,0),method="ML")
write.table(TheForecast,file="C:/....path..../TheForecast.txt",quote=F)

#CODE TO PROVIDE AN EXAMPLE GRAPH AND EXAMPLE FORECAST DATA#
MyForecast <- plot(forecast(TheForecast,h=10))
print(TheForecast)
```

So the line im seeking to fix is therefore:

```
write.table(TheForecast,file="C:/....path..../TheForecast.txt",quote=F)
```

When I try to run it, it will produce the graph, but won't save the forecast data to a txt file. I get this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""Arima"" to a data.frame
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want save the forecast just use xlsx package:

```
library(xlsx)
my_arima <- arima(my_timeseries, order = c(10, 1, 0), method = "ML")
my_forecast <- forecast(my_arima)    

write.xlsx(my_forecast, "my_forecast.xlsx")
#remember to setwd() before.
```

if you want to export the Arima results, try this:

```
sink("My_ARIMA.txt") 
   my_arima   #since you created it before
sink()
```

or

```
sink("My_ARIMA.txt") 
   arima(Y, order = c(10, 1, 0), method = "ML") 
sink()
```

in addicction, take a look to auto.arima funcion. AR(10) maybe is not fully necessary